# calling [mapView addOverlay:] has no effect

Tags: ios, mkmapview, nsdata, mkoverlay

For some reason, when I use [mapView addOverlay:], nothing happens.

Code:

```
NSData* dataLat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"latKey"];
NSArray* overlayLat = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataLat];
double lats[overlayLat.count];
NSData* dataLong = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"longKey"];
NSArray* overlayLong = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataLong];
double longs[overlayLong.count];

for(int iii = 0; iii < overlayLat.count; iii++)
{
    NSNumber* a = (NSNumber*)[overlayLat objectAtIndex:iii];
    lats[iii] = [a doubleValue];
}

for(int iii = 0; iii < overlayLong.count; iii++)
{
    NSNumber* a = (NSNumber*)[overlayLong objectAtIndex:iii];
    longs[iii] = [a doubleValue];
}

int size = (sizeof(lats) / sizeof(lats[0]));

NSLog(@"%d", size);

MKMapPoint points[size];

for(int iii = 0; iii < overlayLong.count; iii++)
{
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointMake(lats[iii], longs[iii]);
    if(lats[iii] != 0)
        points[iii] = point;
}

for(int iii = 0; iii < 15; iii++)
{
    NSLog(@"Lat (x):%f", points[iii].x);
    NSLog(@"Long (y):%f", points[iii].y);
}

MKPolyline* line = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:points count:size];

[mapView addOverlay:line];

NSLog(@"finished");
```

The vast majority of this code just accesses the data and turns it into usable coordinates. My question is (because I know that the coordinates are valid because of the NSLogs), why doesn't anything get added to the mapView when addOverlay: is called? I can post more code if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `polylineWithPoints:count:` method takes a C array of `MKMapPoint` structs.

An `MKMapPoint` is not the same as a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (latitude, longitude).  You are creating `MKMapPoint` structs using `MKMapPointMake` but giving it latitude and longitude values.  Such an `MKMapPoint` is not at the expected location.

Either use `MKMapPointForCoordinate` to create an `MKMapPoint` from lat/long coordinates or, probably easier, create a C array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs and call `polylineWithCoordinates:count:` instead.

Comment: Great, though Craig makes a good point about "missing items".  You're not setting points[iii] if lats[iii] is 0 leaving points[iii] with a garbage value which the map view will either not like and crash or your polyline will look wrong.  Look into why the lats[iii] are 0 to begin with and/or don't include them in the points array at all.  I think what Craig is suggesting is that that process will be easier with an NSMutableArray and to then transfer the results to a C array.  (By the way, a zero latitude and longitude is a perfectly valid and real location.)

Comment: I know that 0 lat 0 long location is a valid location, but it would not exactly be receiving cell reception. I agree, I think that when the data is stored in the first place, only non-zero latitudes and longitudes should be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your 'size' is wrong? Your points array will also have missing items anywhere the source data had 0. I'd go with an NSMutableArray and add items to that if they are deemed valid, then count that at the end and pass it to polylineWithPoints.

Comment: The problem with that is that MKMapPoints are not objects, so putting them in an NSMutableArray is annoying.